# Does every infinite group have a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

This question was asked in abstract algebra quiz and  I am confused about it. So, I am asking for help here.

> Does every infinite group have a subgroup?

I thought about $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ but they have subgroup and the former implies that every infinite cyclic group have subgroup.

So, No progress could be made on this particular question.

Any help please!!

Comment: Consider the cyclic subgroup generated by an element

Comment: *every* group has at least one subgroup – the trivial subgroup :). in addition, any non-trivial group has itself as a subgroup

Comment: if you're looking for a *non-trivial* and *proper* subgroup, then the answer to your question is still yes. since $G$ is infinite, it has a non-identity element $g$. If $g$ has finite order, then $\langle g\rangle$ is a proper non-trivial subgroup of $G$ (why?). On the other hand, if $g$ does not have finite order, consider $\langle g^2\rangle$; can you prove that this is a proper non-trivial subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There always is a proper non-trivial subgroup in any infinite group.

To see why, first note that $\mathbb Z$ has a proper non-trivial subgroup, $2\mathbb Z$. So any group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ has a non-trivial proper subgroup.

Let $G$ be an infinite group not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Note that for any $g\neq0\in G$, there exists a group homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to G$ given by $z\mapsto g^z$. Hence, $(g)$ is isomorphic to a quotient group of $\mathbb Z$, and $(g)\neq(0)$, which means that $(g)$ is proper and non-trivial.

Comment: hmm, as written this isn't quite right – if $g$ has finite order then $\langle g\rangle$ does not embed into $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: (you want to distinguish between the case where $g$ has finite order, in which case $\langle g\rangle$ is *not* isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ but *is* a proper subgroup of $G$ since $G$ is infinite, and the case where $g$ has infinite order, in which case $\langle g\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and hence again a proper subgroup of $G$)

Comment: no worries :) easy typo to make. (also, you of course meant "group homomorphism" rather than "ring homomorphism")